# Rails for Leap 42.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opensuse

How to install Ruby on Rails (v.5.1 or 5.2 ) in OpenSuse Leap 42.3 ? What repositories should I use? The instructions of [this page](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Aruby%3Aextensions&package=rubygem-rails-2_3) do not work.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Do you have ruby installed already?

Comment: "For openSUSE Leap 42.3 run the following as root:
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:ruby/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/devel:languages:ruby.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install ruby2.3" # ->  No provider of 'rubygem-rails-2_3' found.

Comment: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Aruby%3Aextensions&package=rubygem-rails-5_1 #-> No provider of 'rubygem-rails-5_1' found. To devius: Yes, I installed ruby2.3. But I can not install the rails ...

Comment: If you have `ruby` installed you should be able to use the command `gem install rails` to install rails.

Comment: It's a ridiculous advice. Take a look please, this problem can not be solved so simply: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/530475-Rails-for-Leap-42-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to install Ruby on Rails for OpenSuse Leap 42.3:

1. Upgrade from Leap to Tumbleweed.
2. Install rails.